# Are there good actively maintained linux based OS that have great touch support especially for Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: pi-4, touchscreen

I have been working with the [official](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-touch-display/) Raspberry Pi touch display and I must say that it is not as sensitive, responsive or fluid as I expected.

After researching about it on R-Pi forums I realized that its less of a hardware issue and more of an OS level issue. Raspbian is just not the OS for touch first devices.

Keeping that in mind, in 2021, what choices do I have for OSes when it comes to great support for touch and that runs on R-Pi 4? The only requirements being that it should be linux based (not android) and actively maintained and not abandoned like some past projects, for example Ubuntu Touch.

Answer (score 0):

Your question inspired me to do a little more research, having had similar troubles. There’s a good article ‘The Best Linux Distros for a Touchscreen Monitor’ April 2021 [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/best-linux-desktop-touch-enabled-monitor/) making a few general recommendations of which I thought Gnome 3 on Ubuntu sounded pretty doable on RPi. I haven’t tested it myself (yet).

Answer (score 0):

BBN Open Source Marine Linux OS for Raspberry Pi by Bareboat Necessities

is customized for best touchscreen support
(due to need to support cockpit touchscreen chartplotter)

On screen keyboard,
Two finger zoom,
Long touch,
Double finger tap,
Three finger scroll

No finger rotate,
Copy/paste is via on-screen keyboard

It’s basically raspberry pi OS, with 64-bit kernel,
armhf user space. Budgie desktop, openbox window manager. And many customizations.

You can customize OS image yourself
if you are willing to build it on CircleCi.
The scripts are easy to understand if you know
shell scripting.

Or you can just burn SD card with OS image
and follow Getting Started Guide.

https://bareboat-necessities.github.io/my-bareboat/bareboat-os.html

—MG

Answer (score 0):

You can consider Monjaro. Manjaro is a user-friendly Linux distribution based on Arch Linux. Here is a blog on how you can use it on Raspberry Pi: https://raspberrytips.com/install-manjaro-raspberry-pi/